# Using a variable containing spaces as a single argument

Tags: bash

Think you have a variable that contains a string of text with spaces inbetween and you want to use that as input arguments for another script. How would you go about passing the variable content without worrying about the space chars?

The following doesn't work:

```
VAR1=hello\ world
#... do something else
./a_script.sh $VAR1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use double quotes:

```
VAR1=hello\ world
#... do something else
./a_script.sh "$VAR1"
```