# Bash shell is not taking the arguments in a way I would expect?

Tags: git, bash, shell

I run the script below as such

`push repo "message"`

However if my message has spaces in it the script will break. Obviously the interpreter, see any spaces as indication of a new argument.  How can I change the behavior so that I can write a complete commit message with spaces.

```
push() {
  local a=$1 b=$2
  if [ $# -eq 0 ]
  then
     echo "Enter git shortname for first argument"
     return
  fi

  if [ $# -eq 1 ]
  then
      b=$(timestamp)
  fi
  build
  git add -A .
  git commit -m $b
  git push $a
  echo "push() completed."
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a variable containing spaces as a single argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411440/using-a-variable-containing-spaces-as-a-single-argument)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use proper quoting inside your function:

```
push() {
  local a="$1" b="$2"
  if [ $# -eq 0 ]
  then
     echo "Enter git shortname for first argument"
     return
  fi

  if [ $# -eq 1 ]
  then
      b=$(timestamp)
  fi
  build
  git add -A .
  git commit -m "$b"
  git push "$a"
  echo "push() completed."
}
```

Comment: I've never had to quote variables in any other languages, how would one intuit this?

Comment: Yes Unix shell does behave very differently with and without quotes.

Comment: @cadegalt You can read about [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting) in the Bash manual.